# VB .Net - Send String to Another Application

Tags: vb.net, sendmessage, user32

From VB .Net, I'm trying to send a string to a textbox of another application but I cannot make it work. I'm able to get the handle and even set the focus to the textbox but my SendMessage function doesn't seem to be correct as I get the error message "SendMessage' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature."

Here is my code:

```
Module Module1

    Private Const WM_SETTEXT As Int32 = &HC

    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Long
    Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    Private Declare Auto Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hwndParent As IntPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As IntPtr
    Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As IntPtr

    Sub Main()
        Dim AppHwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Test Application"
        Dim WinHwnd1 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(AppHwnd, 0&, "SWT_Window0", vbNullString)
        Dim WinHwnd2 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(WinHwnd1, 0&, "SWT_Window0", vbNullString)
        Dim WinHwnd3 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(WinHwnd2, 0&, "SWT_Window0", vbNullString)
        Dim TextBoxHwnd1 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(WinHwnd3, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
        Dim TextBoxHwnd2 As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(WinHwnd3, TextBoxHwnd1, "Edit", vbNullString)

        MsgBox(TextBoxHwnd2)
        SetForegroundWindow(TextBoxHwnd2)

        SendMessage(TextBoxHwnd2, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, "text")

    End Sub

End Module
```

The line "MsgBox(TextBoxHwnd2)" returns the handle number I found using Window Detective so I'm assuming the code is correct up to this point. Also, I tested "SetForegroundWindow(TextBoxHwnd1)" and the cursor is on the first textbox whereas "SetForegroundWindow(TextBoxHwnd1) sets the cursor on the second textbox.

Comment: Your declaration of `SendMessage` looks suspicious, in particular I would tend to think that `wMsg` and `wParam` should probably be `Integer` rather than `Long`.  Did this originate in legacy VB code (VBA/VB6)?  The length of the `Integer` and `Long` data types changed from legacy VB to VB.NET.

Comment: I just checked, the `Msg` parameter is `UINT` in the Windows API which would end up a `Integer` in VB.  The `wParam` parameter is `UINT_PTR` so it should in fact be `Long` for a 64-bit build, but `Integer` for a 32-bit build; if possible to declare it as `IntPtr` and then pass 0 to it, that would probably be best.

Comment: Fantastic Craig, that solved my problem. Thank you so much!!!! How do I accept a comment as a solution?

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration looks like it might have been migrated from legacy VB code, where `Long` was a 32-bit integer and `Integer` was only 16-bit (dating to legacy VB's origination in 16-bit Windows).  The length of the data types changed in .NET which was created after the shift to universal 32-bit Windows, so `Integer` is 32-bit and `Long` is 64-bit.

Moreover, the Windows API itself needed to be updated for 64-bit Windows.  `SendMessage` is one of the functions that has some parameters that are longer in 64-bit because they are expected to hold pointers.

I checked on the native header file declaration of `SendMessage` and found that:

- The parameter `Msg` is declared as `UINT` which would correspond to `Integer` in VB.  This needs to be changed regardless of whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit build.
- The parameter `wParam` is declared as `UINT_PTR` so it should in fact be `Long` for a 64-bit build, but `Integer` for a 32-bit build; if it's possible to declare it as `IntPtr` and then pass 0 to it, that would probably be best, because it should automatically adjust the length depending on whether you're building for 32-bit or 64-bit.